# Building a predictive algorithm in python using an inspection sensor data of an assembly line (manufacturing)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, scikit-learn, data

We have a manufacturing assembly line. At the end of it, there is a sensor that can measure the final product. There is a set engineering tolerance so the product will be inside the limit (OK) or outside (NOT OK).

What I want to do is using all the previous measured data, try to predict if the next products are going to be outside this tolerance limit.

Is there a model that can be adapted to achieve this?

If it is possible, can it tell me when? (Based on a tendency maybe?)

I am pretty new to all this so thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Gonzo! You asked a very general question, so to familiarize you with the topic of Predictive Maintenance I recommend you this presentation https://youtu.be/wZaTrkIKtE0. It's about prototyping of ML systems based on a Predictive Maintenance project. Some info on approaches, methods, challenges, etc.